# Navigate to specific fragment on BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I've searched my problem but I could not find anything. let me describe my problem.

I have 3 buttons on BottomNavigationView (Home, User, History). then from other activity, I have a button which I want is going to **User** page (with BottomnavigationView of course.

I will show you my code. it still defaults all. I just do not know how to navigate to the User page.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_user, R.id.navigation_notifications
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}}
```

and here is my code (from other fragment)

**otherFragment.kt**

```
buttonRincian.setOnClickListener {
        // i dont know command to go to MainActivity with User page as default selected menu
    }
```

thank you so much, i hoe someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface which your activity will implement.
All the fragments should call the method of the interface wherever you want to change the fragment.

something like

```
interface TabChangeListener {
    fun onTabChange(tabName : String)
}
```

Code in Activity

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), TabChangeListener {
   override fun onTabChange(tabName : String) {
       //code to show different tabs
   }
}
```

Code in Fragments

```
class Frag1 : Fragment {
   var listener : TabChangeListener
   //somewhere in the code
   listener.onTabChange("userTab")
}
```

Don't forget to take the reference of TabChangeListener in Fragments from the activity otherwise the callbacks won't work.

Comment: i dont get it, what is command in that function(onChangeTab)? can you give me an example? my regard..

Comment: I have given you an example, looks like you need some practice with using interfaces. you should search on the internet about passing data from fragment to activity. You will get two solutions but use the one that is using interfaces. Let me know if you still can't figure it out.